# Comparing Dates with Colored Cells in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel file were I have to update Manufacturing ETA's Bi-Weekly.
I have original dates in Column 'E' and The new updated dates in Column 'F'.
I would like to create a system, where every time the new Date is lower than the Previous, it highlights Green, and when the New date is higher than the previous, it highlights RED. If the date didn't change at all, nothing happens.

Could anyone guide me, on a solution please? I appreciate it.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show your formula!

Comment: Very simple to do with conditional formatting. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-conditional-formatting-in-Excel-34402f91-c7e7-4060-944c-65d913033d18

Comment: Welcome to the site.  We would like to see what you have so far!

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! So Far I have tried this for the ones I wanted to turn Green : Conditional Formatting> New Rule> Use a Formula to Determine which cells to format: =$E$3:$E$543<$F$3:$F$543

Or the ones I want to Turn Red I used this formula: $E$3:$E$543>$F$3:$F$543.

When I check apply nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Clear CF from ColumnsE:F, select from E3 to wherever suits and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$E3<$F3
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then repeat with:

```
=$E3>$F3
```

for green fill.

This will highlight (or not) the cells in pairs.